# Tridion GUI performance optimization

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Recently we upgraded from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1.  Initially performance of Tridion GUI was very good.  But as we converted all VBScript templates to compound templates we have to publish entire site (around 1600 pages and 5000 components).  After publishing the site we found that Tridion GUI became very slow, also publishing queue is taking lot of time to get loaded, can anyone suggest some performance optimization tips on CMS servers as well as SQL Database.

Comment: This is a pretty open question, you may want to try to break it into smaller Q&A style question. I'll try to answer some but keep mindful that this type of question doesn't fit the Q&A format of Stack Overflow

Comment: Did you already have a look at the CM maintenance topic in the online help? http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_1236E6822ECB47748C15CCF4F94E25B9 (log in required)

Comment: When you say "After publishing the site", do you mean "After we queued the site for publishing" or "After the publish of the site had completed"?

Answer (score 7):

Clearly your performance impact is due to your publisher rather than the CME/IIS, since you state that

> After publishing the site we found that Tridion GUI became very slow

What happened after all pages were published?

The CME (Content Manager Explorer) and the Publisher are separate processes and we tend to install them on different machines precisely to avoid this type of resource bottlenecks.

Have you considered that perhaps the process of converting to Modular Templates wasn't very successful or sufficiently tested from a performance point of view?

Anyway, there is no quick solution. Reduce publisher throughput by limiting the number of render threads if CME response is more important than publishing throughput. Add a machine to deal with publishing, if publishing performance is important enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

For Publish Queue performance please use the Purge tool on the server to delete successful publish transactions.  This is important when bulk publishing in both the older and new version of Tridion .